# How do I type a schwa character - ǝ (the upside-down e) on MacOS?

Tags: macos, keyboard

I have tried following instructions that say its in the emojis and symbols but the upside down e is not in there for me.

Then there is a hot key about Option + Shift and then Option + A, that has not worked for me either.

What keys or input methods can make this easier than cut and paste?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Emoji & Symbols, type schwa in the search box.

On the ABC Extended input source, type option shift semicolon, let go and then type e.     ǝ

Comment: The ABC parts needs some elaboration, as it didn'T work for me at first, the on-screen kbd display being confusing for the desired result. (Although your description turned out correct, once I realised my errors…)

Comment: The first line of instructions did it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you need it a lot, you can put one in your typing replacer.

System Prefs > Keyboard > Text

Add your text to type on the left, then paste a schwa into the right, then you've got one every time you need one…

[image]